# Is "to ease" the same as "could ease"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, american-english, to-infinitive

Found this article online and the title is:

- [China-U.S. trade war to ease but conflicts will persist - former finance minister](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trade-china/china-u-s-trade-war-to-ease-but-conflicts-will-persist-former-finance-minister-idUSKBN1XJ04V)

But then the person is quoted of saying "could ease". Are the two equivalent? Because in my book, they're not equivalent at all. "To ease" meaning it will ease and not could ease.

Comment: I agree that "to" here does suggest "will." However, for better or worse, titles of news articles are not usually 100% accurate. They favor shorter words and may try to be more sensational.

Comment: Both syntactically and semantically, there's no difference between *Trade war **to ease** but conflicts **will persist*** and *Trade war **will ease** but conflicts **to persist***. But *idiomatically*, we're more likely to apply the ***to*** version to future actions that are ***planned, intended***, rather than ***expected*** (but perhaps *unwanted*). In the cited example, both "future actions" are effectively portrayed as ***inevitable, definite***, so there's no suggestion of ***could*** (which strongly implies ***but perhaps might not***).

Answer (score 2):

You are totally correct.  The headline is simply not an accurate summary of the article.

"to ease" makes a definite predication.

"could ease" asserts a possibility.

Different people in a news agency write the articles (journalists) and the headlines (editors), and sometimes the editors don't read very well.